# Realm app size in comparison to Core Data

Tags: ios, database, swift2, realm

Does using Realm on your application cause it to take up more space on disk than if I stored the same amount of data with Core Data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm leverages bit-packing and smart column optimizations to be generally ~50% smaller than SQLite. CoreData is based on the latter.

The support of native links in Realm, allows you to optimize your schema and avoid duplicating data in foreign keys, which can also help to reduce the file size beside the clear performance benefits.